# Is it possible to send a message to all threads?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi

I'm using message queues (provided by windows) to help several threads in my program communicate. However, I need to send a message to all threads in my program at once. Is there any function to do this?

Comment: Why? They can't all begin processing at the same instant, so what is the problem with calling PostThreadMessage N times?

Comment: I'll sometimes have a variable number of threads, so it would be a hassle to figure out which threads to send it to.

Comment: Have you tried posting to HWND_BROADCAST? I'm not sure exactly what conditions have to be met for a thread to receive that. It may require a top-level window on each thread, I'm just not certain. If you use HWND_BROADCAST, make sure you use RegisterWindowMessage.

Comment: Broadcasting is probably not a good idea since it is desktop-wide, but there is nothing in the API for process-wide broadcasting of messages. I think you're going to have to maintain a list of active thread ids.

Comment: Okay, I think I've got a good idea on how I would do that. Thanks for the help

Comment: Alternately you could enumerate your process' threads, but that might be a bit expensive each time you want to broadcast a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain thread messages (without a window) are unreliable in Windows --- there are circumstances under which they get swallowed without a trace, and without your thread getting a chance to handle them. I therefore like to have a top-level window per thread for the message target, since window-targetted messages always get processed by the window procedure for that window. You can make it a message-only window (with a parent of `HWND_MESSAGE`) if you don't need a visible window for that thread.

Once you have a window for each thread, you can just enumerate the windows with `EnumWindows` or `EnumChildWindows`, and send messages to the ones you want. Or, you can keep a list of thread message windows, and send a message to each. There is no simple way to send a message to all threads in a process.

Comment: They get missed during system-modal loops because your message pump is not running. If you don't have any visible windows and don't call MessageBox or DialogBox, you won't be running any system-modal loops.

Comment: Sadly, those aren't the only functions that include a message pump (and therefore drop thread messages). IIRC use of COM components can cause thread messages to drop under some circumstances, for example.

Comment: Ah yes, COM.. Never been a fan. Avoid like the plague. Isn't COM dead yet? ;)